# How do i export materials in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to export materials from my object so that for example in unity I can open it, add lighting and that it actually changes according to the lighting. So basically i want to export my materials with the bumps, reflections and transparancy. I made it in cycles.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Yeah i read that but I don't understand what they mean since if you bake a texture all you get is just a flat image with no information  on transparancy, bumps and reflections